# Different behavior of interrupt exceptions

Tags: java

When I run `Test1` no `interrupt` exception is shown, but when I run `Test2` an `interrupt` exception appears.

I really want to know reason behind this.

```
public class Test1 {
        public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            int a = 10;
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            System.out.println(a);
            }
        }
```

When I run the following program, the exception is there, and I am really not sure why, even if it is not waiting (i.e. the queue is empty).

```
 public class Test2 {
        public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            BlockingQueue<Integer> q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>(2);
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            System.out.println(q.take());
            }
        }
```

Please help me understand why java is behaving like this.

Thanks.